# Update column of blob type_ MySQL

Tags: mysql, blob, mysql-workbench, uppercase, lowercase

I have a database with columns aes_encrypted.
For example, the column email has been aes_encrypted and is of blob type. The issue I am facing is that in this column, there are email addresses that are of upper case.

I want to update all the values in this column and set it to lowercase.

The below is just for testing on a particular record:

```
update lms_systest_db.member_tb
set email= aes_encrypt(lower(`email`),'$key')
where cast(aes_decrypt(fname,'$key') as char) = "John" ;
```

> When I use the above query, it returns null.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Email addresses are **not case sensitive** so from what you describe I don't think this matters. If this matters to you from a *presentation* point of view then simply change the case of the decoded address upon output.

Comment: If column is already encrypted then you must decrypt it, then convert to needed case, and then encrypt back. I.e. you loose 1st step.